# Language wont change

Tags: android, locale

I'm trying to set the language of my app programatically, but it changes only some of my strings. I have values folder where are the default strings in english. Then I created values-fr and translated every string to french myself, so now I have (english) default values folder where I have my english strings.xml and values-fr folder where I have my french strings.xml

and here is the code that I use to change the language onCreate and onResume:

```
String languageToLoad  = "fr"; // your language
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

but it only changes some of the strings, for example all strings in my preference get changed, but the strings in main activity remain the same. Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: Is that code called before inflating your activity view?

Comment: Remove `getBaseContext()`. Try `getResources()...` instead `getBaseContext().getResources()...`

Comment: yes it is called in onCreate and also in onResume

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Resources standardResources = getApplicationContext();
DisplayMetrics metrics = standardResources.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration config = new Configuration(standardResources.getConfiguration());
config.locale = new Locale("fr") // change
standardResources.updateConfiguration(config, metrics);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Locale localeFR = new Locale("fr", "FR");
Resources res = getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = localeFR;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
Intent refresh = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(refresh);
finish();
```

Once you set the locale for your app, you need to restart the activity in order to make the changes visible.